# Python CSV cant encode character

Tags: python, csv, unicode, ascii

Using Python an Beautiful Soup, I have created a script that takes the name, address and phone number of businesses off a website and the output is saved into three columns of a CSV file.

The script works fine but it stops when I get to a business name that is as follows:

`u'\nLevel 12, 280 George Street SYDNEY\xa0 NSW\xa0 2000. .  Sydney. NSW 2000\n'`

The problem is the "xa0" part. The error message states:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)`

I have a vague idea of what this error means but have no idea how to deal with it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:

My script is as follows:

```
import bs4
import requests

page = requests.get('http://accountantlist.com.au/x123-Accountants-in-Sydney.aspx?Page=0')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content)

for company in soup.select('table#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgLawyers tr > td > table'):
     name = company.a.text
     address = company.find_all('tr')[1].text
     phone = company.tr.find_all('td')[1].text
     with open('/home/kwal0203/Desktop/eggs.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
             s = csv.writer(csvfile)
             s.writerow([name,address,phone])
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code you're using that causes the error, along with the complete traceback.

Comment: So you are getting this error while writing to your csv file. Can you share us how you arre writing your csv file?

Comment: I've added the script to the question but not sure how to get the traceback?

Comment: Sorry I've left out part of the script. One second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode it to `utf-8` format while writing to csv file as Python's built-in `csv` doesn't supports unicode.

```
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i)<128)


name = remove_non_ascii(company.a.text)
address = remove_non_ascii(company.find_all('tr')[1].text)
phone = remove_non_ascii(company.tr.find_all('td')[1].text)

with open('/home/kwal0203/Desktop/eggs.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    s = csv.writer(csvfile)
    s.writerow([data.encode("utf-8") for data in [name,address,phone]])
```

Or you can install [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.9.4) which supports unicode by default.

You can install it like this.

```
pip install unicodecsv
```

Comment: Hi when I use your code I get an error message saying: `TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported`

Comment: Can you include a sample of [name,address,phone] in your question so that i can try out your data.

Comment: I don't have the data in a file. I just scrape it off this website `http://accountantlist.com.au/x123-Accountants-in-Sydney.aspx` using the script I wrote.

Comment: This is the problem text: `u'\nLevel 12, 280 George Street SYDNEY\xa0 NSW\xa0 2000. .  Sydney. NSW 2000\n'`. The `xa0` part that encloses `NSW`

Comment: Try using `s.writerow([data.encode("utf-8") for data in [name,address,phone]])`.

Comment: @martineau Thanks even i tried to encode it as its already in decoded format. Its working.

Comment: @Kane Please check now. As you were getting decoded value already we need to encode it while writing.

Comment: @TanveerAlam great thanks Tanveer. When I do this it looks like this: `"Level 12, 280 George Street SYDNEY┬á NSW┬á 2000. .  Sydney. NSW 2000"`.. you see those weird symbols? Are they supposed to be there?

Comment: @Kane Yes kane those weird symbols are accents. Many religinal languages have accents so english char a and á are different in sence of sound you can say. If the answer was helpful for you please raise and accept it.

Comment: @TanveerAlam yes I will accept. But do you know how I can get rid of: `┬á` this symbol in the output? `┬á NSW┬á` should just be `NSW`

Comment: @kane See i have added another function remove_non_ascii. What it does is it takes each char checks whether its ascii(ord<128)) and returns word by removing non ascii values.